# Bad PTS values with mediacodec aac encoder

Tags: android, encoding, android-mediacodec, aac

I'm trying to transcode an audio stream with media codec, everything looks fine until I try to play it with VLC. The audio stops every few seconds and when I looked at the warnings, vlc tells me "*playback way too early (-141928): playing silence*" or "*playback way too late*". I managed to track the issue after looking to vlc source code, the drift (between the pts received and the expect) was too high/low, so it must be a pts issue.

I looked at the decoders input timestamps and they are fine, however, the encoder output timestamps were not, sometimes the pts diff (between the current encoded audio sample and the last one) was 1890 and other times it was 2090. I managed to get it working correctly if I manually set the pts (by increasing it with 2090 at each sample).

At this moment I don't know why the aac encoder pts values are incorrect, any suggestions?
Another strange behaviour I noticed: this only happens for certain values of sample rate when configuring the codec. Below is the code used to configure the codec:

```
MediaFormat formatAudio = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat("audio/mp4a-latm", 44100, 2);   // AAC Low Overhead Audio Transport Multiplex
formatAudio.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC);
formatAudio.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 64000);
formatAudio.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE,655360); 
ByteBuffer csd = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
csd.put(0, (byte) (2 << 3 | 4 >> 1));
csd.put(1, (byte)((4 & 0x01) << 7 | 2 << 3));
formatAudio.setByteBuffer("csd-0", csd);
```

This configuration will output a broken audio stream, however if I change the sample rate (to 48000 for example) and adjust the csd-0 the output will be correct (the pts diff between encoded audio samples is always the same and correct).

Finally, I am using ADTS headers and muxing the audio to ts with FFmpeg, but I think the issue has to due with aac encoding with a sample rate of 44100 (when I used mediamuxer I had the same issues with the audio).

Comment: What is the original sample rate? Are you experiencing this issue only if you transcode 44.1khz -> 44.1khz but not 48khz -> 48khz? MediaCodec does not resample for you.

Comment: Sorry for the let reply. The original sample rate was 48khz and I was trying to resample to 44.1khz, I was not expecting I had to manually resample audio. I understand why I need to resample video (when transcoding) since we are trying to render a frame into a smaller/bigger surface, but why do we need to (also) resample the audio? is it not raw audio data that we are trying to encode? and how does it work?